# How to set cookies in Nitro (Nuxt 3)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

In my `nuxt.config.js` s set this nitro configuration.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      '/api/**': {
        proxy: 'https://dev.project.com/api/**',
      },
    },
  }
});
```

But application 'dev.project.com' (Laravel) response is error 401.

I guess, it happens because my cookies was wrong.
How i can to auto set right cookies in nitro config?

Or how i can get proxy in else way?

Answer (score 2):

Try the useRequestHeaders composable. In my case it works.

Some snippet from my code

```
const customFetch = $fetch.create({
headers: { 'trace-id': uuidv4() },
onRequest({ request, options }) {
  if (process.server) {
    // Add cooki header to provide session and not getting 401 from /api/auth
    options.headers = useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
  }
},
})

customFetch(request, opts)
```

See https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#pass-cookies-from-server-side-api-calls-on-ssr-response or https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#passing-headers-and-cookies for more